# Using array index variables instead of hard coded values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a following method, I want to use three variables declared in the 1st three lines instead of checking hard coded values using for loop and add it to res. I was trying following so that I only have to change the values inside successStates & failedStates

```
//    if(successStates.find(x => x === filterVal)){
//         filter1 = successStates[0];
//         filter2 = successStates[1];
//    } 

getJobFilter() {
  let successStates = ['ACCEPTED_STATE', 'ACTIVE_STATE'];
  let failedStates = ['INACTIVE_STATE'];
  let otherStates = ['UNKNOWN'];
  let res = [];
  let filter =
    JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('cdgFilter') || '{}');
  for (let key in filter) {
    if (key) {
      if (key === 'collection_status') {
        let filterVal: any;
        let filter1, filter2;

        if (filterVal === "SUCCESSFUL") {
          filter1 = 'ACTIVE_STATE';
          filter2 = 'ACCEPTED_STATE';
        } else if (filterVal === "FAILED") {
          filter1 = 'UNKNOWN_STATE';
          filter2 = 'INACTIVE_STATE';
        }
        res.push({
          'field': 'State',
          'value': filter1
        }, {
          'field': 'State',
          'value': filter2
        });
      } else {
        res.push({
          'field': key,
          'value': filter[key].filter
        });
      }
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Where do you set `filterVal`? `let filterVal: any;` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Why does `failedStates` only have one element instead of two? Where does `UNKNOWN_STATE` come from? Should it be `let failedStates = ['UNKNOWN_STATE', 'INACTIVE_STATE'];`?

Comment: Using typescript here - filterVal? let filterVal: any. UNKNOWN is to be treated separately, can treat as 3rd variable may be..

Comment: Is `filterVal()` something that comes out of `filter[key]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a map object:

```
const collectionStatusFilters = {
  SUCCESSFUL: ['ACTIVE_STATE', 'ACCEPTED_STATE'],
  FAILED: ['UNKNOWN_STATE', 'INACTIVE_STATE']
}
```

You can then replace your if statement thusly:

```
const filters = collectionStatusFilters[filterVal];
res = res.concat(
  filters.map(filter => ({
    field: 'State',
    value: filter
  }))
);
```

Comment: Why are you using `res.concat()`? `res` is initially empty, you can just set it to the result of `filters.map()`

Comment: The code is hosted in a loop, which has a `res.push` in one of the branches. This is just to allow the code to co-exist with what's already there.

Comment: It has `res.push()` in both branches.

Comment: Yes, and in one of the branches, I replaced the push with `res.concat()`. The point is that res may not be initially empty because something may have been pushed into it.

Comment: And now I see that one of the branches pushes two objects, the other only pushes one.